# Afex:mixed() is pulling wrong column and not using formula I have set to call

Tags: r, mixed-models

Afex::mixed() is pulling the wrong column of data and not using the formula I have set for it to use. I use the numbered column because the actual names of the data are not useable in these formulas due to special characters.

It is off by 3 columns from what is in the Formula column.

```
library(purrr)
library(afex)
library(tidyverse) 

res.aov<- ANOVAprep %>% 
  mutate(
    Formula = map(names, ~as.formula(paste(.x, "~ col2*col3 + (1| col1)"))),
    linregmod = map(Formula, ~mixed(.x, data = df4)),
    filtered_ANOVA = map(linregmod, pluck, "anova_table"),
```

This is the data I'm using that is causing the issue.

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(col1 = c("Subject", "sub001", "sub001", "sub001", 
"sub001", "sub001", "sub001", "sub006", "sub006", "sub006", "sub006", 
"sub006", "sub006", "sub010", "sub010", "sub010", "sub010", "sub010", 
"sub010", "sub011", "sub011", "sub011", "sub011", "sub011", "sub011", 
"sub013", "sub013", "sub013", "sub013", "sub013", "sub013", "sub016", 
"sub016", "sub016", "sub016", "sub016", "sub016", "sub018", "sub018", 
"sub018", "sub018", "sub018", "sub018", "sub021", "sub021", "sub021", 
"sub021", "sub021", "sub021", "sub022", "sub022", "sub022", "sub022", 
"sub022", "sub022", "sub023", "sub023", "sub023", "sub023", "sub023", 
"sub023", "sub024", "sub024", "sub024", "sub024", "sub024", "sub024"
), col2 = structure(c(7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), levels = c("0", "0.25", 
"0.5", "1", "2", "30", "Timepoint"), class = "factor"), col3 = c("Genotype", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B"), col477 = c("pop1", "2397", "434", "547.4", "469", "330.2", 
NA, "515", "1507", "1269", "1612", "2292", NA, "463", "4072", 
"1198", "1425", "1167", NA, "111", "32", "133", "87", "16", "138", 
"0", "156.69999999999999", "0", "0", "18", NA, "176", "136", 
"157", "113", "188", "72", "641", "350", "337", "444", "1473", 
NA, "110", "23", "2133", "0", "0", "127", "857", "986.9", "1421", 
NA, "840", NA, "490.3", "593", "353", "536", NA, "1495", "574.70000000000005", 
"0", "58", "2962", "0", NA), col478 = c("pop2", "1446", "980", 
"1128", "936", "968", NA, "1824", "2080", "2071", "2006", "1799", 
NA, "982", "976", "882", "951", "1079", NA, "119", "126", "140", 
"136", "51", "187", "93.3", "167", "114", "76", "138", NA, "428", 
"485", "692", "570", "566", "385", "833", "1085", "1187", "1264", 
"1141", NA, "404", "477", "229", "282", "242", "226", "574", 
"1318", "1141", NA, "984", NA, "612", "692", "694", "612", NA, 
"432", "2087", "295", "139", "236", "291", NA), col479 = c("pop3", 
"2922", "5025", "5454", "5032", "4225.8", NA, "11872", "16101", 
"13443", "13145", "13060", NA, "7100", "8789", "9309", "7758", 
"8577", NA, "371", "379", "514", "459", "282", "460", "0", "639", 
"530", "476", "684", NA, "3093", "4075", "4595", "4526", "4000", 
"4196", "2866", "5062", "5643.1", "5105.8", "5745", NA, "1828", 
"1707", "1779", "1414", "1689", "1266", "5321.6", "8827", "8940", 
NA, "7004.3", NA, "4590", "4876", "5957", "5110", NA, "3245", 
"747", "1194", "733", "1301", "1258", NA), col480 = c("pop4", 
"1914", "1190", "4930", "12463", "7749", NA, "4118.3", "23390", 
"9634", "12350", "15303", NA, "10427", "2120", "6286", "8579", 
"5314", NA, "184", "1047", "1427", "1086", "975", "879", "0", 
"200", "421", "683", "301", NA, "1970", "6210", "4934", "6546", 
"9516", "68", "2763", "1925", "7537", "7231", "6034", NA, "1339", 
"8708", "5538", "861", "812", "1305", "7153", "11860", "9174", 
NA, "6449", NA, "4986", "5624.4", "7774", "4655", NA, "2565", 
"2075", "1031", "1970", "1510", "3251", NA), col481 = c("pop5", 
"2928", "5088", "5457", "4982", "4177.7", NA, "12950", "16045", 
"13802", "13315", "12898", NA, "7049", "9067", "9345", "7741", 
"8751", NA, "360", "369", "496", "449", "276", "447", "13.4", 
"648", "535", "477", "691", NA, "3100", "4065", "4568", "4498", 
"3931", "4230", "2867", "5132", "5619.1", "5074.1000000000004", 
"5736", NA, "1891", "1589", "1712", "1448", "1712", "1260", "5202.6000000000004", 
"8679", "8932", NA, "7017.4", NA, "4514", "4816", "5817", "5062", 
NA, "3311", "687", "1115", "462", "1265", "1167", NA), col482 = c("pop6", 
"7642", "9398", "9084", "8019", "9315", NA, "12976", "17003", 
"14201", "13580", "13513", NA, "7424", "8968", "9048", "7804", 
"8729", NA, "596", "636", "822", "708", "391", "766", "528", 
"982", "913", "669", "914", NA, "3711", "4418", "4817", "4849", 
"4382", "4329", "4556.2", "5580", "6302.2", "6255", "6702", NA, 
"1918", "1850", "1771", "1438", "1663", "1292", "5290.7", "8903", 
"9023", NA, "6913.2", NA, "4671", "4983", "6029", "5201", NA, 
"3300", "747", "1500", "883", "1360", "1295", NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-67L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Code for the dataframe I am trying to mutate

```
####Make Timepoint Factor####
df$col2<- as.factor(df$col2)

####Make new df of names####
populations <- t(df[1,]) 
nnames<- names(df)
nnames<- as.data.frame(nnames)
ANOVAprep<- bind_cols(nnames,populations)
ANOVAprep<- ANOVAprep %>% rename(populations = ...2)
ANOVAprep<- ANOVAprep %>% rename(names = nnames)
ANOVAprep<- ANOVAprep[4:9,]

####Prep for ANOVA####
df1<- df[-1,]
df2<- df1[,1:3]
df3<-lapply(df1[,4:9], as.numeric)
df4<- bind_cols(df2,df3)
df4$col3<- as.factor(df4$col3)
```

Comment: could we have a [mcve] please? (You should be able to use 'special' characters in formulas by backtick-protecting them ...)

Comment: Thanks, this is getting closer.  Can you please define `names` in your code? It would also be good to include the required package-loading statements (at least `library("afex"); library("tidyverse")`)

Comment: Sorry it kept saying that I had too much code in answer to post.

Comment: Hmm.  Can you show some output?  When I run your code from beginning to end and compare `ANOVAprep$names[1]`, `res.aov$Formula[[1]]`, `res.aov$linregmod[[1]]`, and `res.aov$filtered_ANOVA[[1]]`, they appear to match: they all refer to `col477` as the response variable. Are you seeing something different, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: When I manually enter what you typed I get matching results. But in the mutated dataframe res.aov it is incorrectly assigning the 4th column to the first row and so on for me. Sorry I don't know if there is a better way to show you.

Comment: The first row of my res.aov dataframe has res.aov[[4]][[4]][["data"]]
     col7 col2         col3     col1 . And uses the matching plucked res.aov[[5]][[4]][["anova_table"]]. However, the command to pluck the p.values from the ANOVA table uses the correct res.aov[[5]][[1]][["anova_table"]]